# Why do some browsers automatically "resize" the text area on a page?

Tags: html, css

Here is my website: sanyigarazs.atw.hu

And at the "Kapcsolat" page, there is a text area.

In Google Chrome, it resizes to the right size, but in some browsers (Edge, Mozilla) the other elements of the page are wider than the text area and it is annoying.

Here is my markup:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Kapcsolat</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainn.css">
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Sanyigarázs</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="rolunk.html">Rólunk</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Kapcsolat</a></li>
                            <li><a href="weboldalrol.html">Weboldalról</a></li>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <form class="form-inline">
                            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Ide írja keresését." aria-label="Keresés">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Keresés</button>
                        </form> -->
                    </div>
            </nav>
            <div>
                <h3 align="center">Hívjanak telefonon: 06999999999</h3>
                <hr>
                <h5 align="center">Vagy üzenjenek e-mailen keresztül:</h5>
                <form id="uzenetes" action="emailtest.php" method="post">
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center"><input type="text" placeholder="Az ön neve" name="username"
                            size="20" maxlength="150" width="150"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center"><input placeholder="Az ön e-mail címe" type="text" name="address"
                            size="20" maxlength="150" width="150"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center"><input type="text" placeholder="Az üzenet tárgya" name="subject"
                        size="20" maxlength="150"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Ide írja üzenetét..."  size="20" maxlength="150"></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input id="button" type="submit"
                            value="Elküldés"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>

form { 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width:240px;
    font-size: 150%;
    }
    td {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
    }



    textarea {
        width: 230px;
        margin-top: 0%;
        resize: vertical;
    }
    #mobile {
        padding: 30px;
    }
    body {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    }
    .thumbnail {
    transition: all 0.2s;
    }
    .thumbnail:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    p {
    text-align: center;
    }
    .jumbotron {
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .tested {
    font-size: 140%;
    }
    .bug {
    padding: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    }
    .navbar-inverse {
    transition: all 0.2s;
    }
    .navbar-inverse:hover {
    transform: scale(1.03);
    } 
    .weboldalroltext {
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
    body { 
    padding-top: 70px; 
    }
    .mainHeader {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    }
    .navbar {
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 20px;
    }
    a:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: solid 3px #fff;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    a:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    }
    .helloka {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 25px;
    }
    hr {
    height: 10px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    form {  
    padding-top: 10px;
    }
    h5 {
    font-size: 18px;
    }
```

So I want to make the  textarea's size equal to the other elements (230px), but it works only in chrome browser.

Thanks for your help, Kristof.

Comment: Note that `<meta>` and `<input>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, edit your HTML code.

Remove the `textarea` element's `size` attribute and `input` element's `width` attribute in your HTML, because they are not valid. And, You don't need to use `size=20` for `input`s because this is default.

Then, change your CSS like this:

```
input[type="text"],
textarea {
  width: 230px /* or you can use 100% */
  /* P.S. The resize option is not supported by Edge */
}
```

```css
form { 
margin: 0 auto; 
width:240px;
font-size: 150%;
}

td {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea {
  width: 230px
}

textarea {
    margin-top: 0%;
    resize: vertical;
}

#mobile {
    padding: 30px;
}

body {
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.thumbnail {
transition: all 0.2s;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
transform: scale(1.1);
}

p {
text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron {
border: 1px solid black;
}

.tested {
font-size: 140%;
}

.bug {
padding: 15px;
border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.navbar-inverse {
transition: all 0.2s;
}

.navbar-inverse:hover {
transform: scale(1.03);
} 

.weboldalroltext {
padding-bottom: 3px;
}

body { 
padding-top: 70px; 
}

.mainHeader {
padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.navbar {
padding-top: 5px;
font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand {
font-size: 20px;
}

a:after {
display: block;
content: '';
border-bottom: solid 3px #fff;
transform: scaleX(0);
transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

a:hover:after {
transform: scaleX(1);
}

.helloka {
width: 300px;
font-size: 25px;
}

hr {
height: 10px;
border: 0;
box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

form {  
padding-top: 10px;
}

h5 {
font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Kapcsolat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainn.css">
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Sanyigarázs</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="rolunk.html">Rólunk</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kapcsolat</a></li>
                        <li><a href="weboldalrol.html">Weboldalról</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <form class="form-inline">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Ide írja keresését." aria-label="Keresés">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Keresés</button>
                    </form> -->
                </div>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <h3 align="center">Hívjanak telefonon: 06999999999</h3>
            <hr>
            <h5 align="center">Vagy üzenjenek e-mailen keresztül:</h5>
            <form id="uzenetes" action="emailtest.php" method="post">
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" placeholder="Az ön neve" name="username" maxlength="150"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><input placeholder="Az ön e-mail címe" type="text" name="address" maxlength="150"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" placeholder="Az üzenet tárgya" name="subject" maxlength="150"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Ide írja üzenetét..."  maxlength="150"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input id="button" type="submit"
                        value="Elküldés"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Every browser have their own predefined css stylesheet. To standardize it use "reset css" snippet. You can find some code in google.

Put it in reset.css file and link it in head section before including mainn.css.

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
```